# PHP - Generating tokens for transactions

Tags: php, token, banking

I need to generate one time use only and unique like [Stripe](http://www.stripe.com) tokens for a banking application (production only) to represent accounts and transactions, what would be a secure and appropriate method of doing this?

Could I use [`random_bytes()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php)?

It would be preferable if the tokens were alphanumeric and not just numbers.
For example, Stripe tokens look like `tok_382r1O2IZ7IgsfwNFATX4xax`

Comment: Additionally to provided answers - you might have used `base64` since it would be shorter than `bin2hex`

Answer (score 15):

You can use the function bin2hex to convert the bytes to a base 62 string.

```
$token = bin2hex(random_bytes(16)); //generates a crypto-secure 32 characters long
```

You can easily prefix this by just appending a string to the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following:

`bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8))`

[Here are the docks](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) on how to use this to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 7 the new [`random_bytes()`](https://secure.php.net/random_bytes) function is a secure random number/string generator and is the recommended way to do this ion PHP.

If you haven't migrated to PHP 7 yet there is a compatible alternative for PHP 5 at Github called [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat).

Comment: Thanks, I have came across `random_bytes()` as i'm using PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static function generateToken($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $token = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $token .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $token;
}
```

Comment: This function doesn't provide a safe implementation. Better use a more secure approach such as the `random_bytes()` function.